# Avoid overlapping line on a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I miss my self during a simple process to create an  array (programing concept) and make some line under the array to indicate some range.

My actual status if the following

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{nodeidx}
\setcounter{nodeidx}{1}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\nodes}[1]{%
    \foreach \num in {#1}{
      \node[minimum size=6mm, draw, rectangle] (\arabic{nodeidx}) at (\arabic{nodeidx},0) {\num};
      \stepcounter{nodeidx}
    }
}

\newcommand{\brckt}[4]{% from, to, lvl, text
  \draw (#1.south west) ++($(-.1, -.1) + (-.1*#3, 0)$) -- ++($(0,-.1) + (0,-#3*1.25em)$) -- node [below] {#4} ($(#2.south east) + (.1,-.1) + (.1*#3, 0) + (0,-.1) + (0,-#3*1.25em)$) -- ++($(0,#3*1.25em) + (0,.1)$);%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pgftransparencygroup
            \nodes{2, 4, 3, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 7}
            \endpgftransparencygroup
            \pgftransparencygroup
            \brckt{1}{6}{0}{Query(0, 5)}
            \endpgftransparencygroup
            \pgftransparencygroup
            \brckt{4}{10}{0}{Query(3, 9)}
            \endpgftransparencygroup
          \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{center}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

And I want to avoid the overlapping between the line, like in this pictures

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution plus some tips:

- no need for an external counter, you can use `count` from `foreach`
- your command for the bracket was a bit needlessly complicated. There's a little bit of my own taste here, but I think you'll like mine.
- one `\usetikzlibrary` is enough, keeps everything compacted and ordered.
- the `level` is now an optional argument, so you don't need to give it if not needed.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,
    %arrows.meta,
    %shapes.multipart,
    %arrows
}
                
\newcommand{\nodes}[1]{%
    \foreach \num [count=\n starting from 0] in {#1}{% no need for an external counter
      \node[minimum size=6mm, draw, rectangle] (n\n) at (\n,0) {\num};
    }
}

\newcommand{\brckt}[4][1]{% [ lvl ] { from, to, text }
    \coordinate (left) at ($(n#2.south west)+(-2mm,-1mm)$);
    \coordinate (right) at ($(n#3.south east)+(2mm,-1mm)$);
    \draw (left) -- ($(left)+(0,-1mm*#1)$) --node[below,midway,font=\scriptsize] {#4} ($(right)+(0,-1mm*#1)$) -- (right);
}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            %\pgftransparencygroup
            \nodes{2, 4, 3, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 7}
            %\endpgftransparencygroup
            %\pgftransparencygroup
            \brckt[2]{0}{5}{Query(0, 5)}
            %\endpgftransparencygroup
            %\pgftransparencygroup
            \brckt{3}{9}{~~~~~~~Query(3, 9)}% used ~ to push the label
            %\endpgftransparencygroup
          \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With use of loops, libraries `chains` and `positioning`, and determining different amplitudes for brackets (`\brckt`):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, 
                positioning}

\newcommand{\brckt}[4]{% from, to, lvl, text
  \draw (#1.south west) -- ++(0,-#3) -|  node[pos=0.25, below] {#4} (#2.south east); % <---
                        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm,
  start chain = going right,
N/.style = {draw, minimum size = 5mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=1mm,
            below=2mm, on chain} % <---
                        ]
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {2, 4, 3, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 7} % <---
\node (n\j) [N] {\i};
\brckt{n1}{n6}{1mm}{Query(0, 5)} % <---
\brckt{n4}{n10}{2mm}{Query(3, 9)}% <---
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]